# Run jquery script on form submit to add additional POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am attempting to add in some previously declared data to an outgoing post matrix.
Unfortunately, I have determined that all efforts to halt the post process, add in the data, and then send it on, have gone unnoticed. Even stripping the script to a simple event stop is overlooked.
Anyhelp?

Comment: Please give some code samples what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good solution in jquery:

get the click event on submit button:

```
$('#mySubmit').click(function(e){//submit is clicked
   e.preventDefault();//stop the submit
   $('#myForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="myNewPost" value="1"/>');//append the new Post vars
   $('#myForm').submit();//submit the form
})
```